# pyramid starter Scaffold error

Tags: python, pyramid

After I install starter Scaffold as shon here: http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/project.html I see error:

File "/home/dima/PycharmProjects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-1.0.9-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/performance.py", line 147, in nav_subtitle
    utime = self._end_rusage.ru_utime - self._start_rusage.ru_utime

AttributeError: 'PerformanceDebugPanel' object has no attribute '_end_rusage'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have properly setup your Python environment and installed Pyramid.
http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/install.html

Verify that your installation is correct with a single-file app.
http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/firstapp.html

In addition, documentation is being revised in the master branch and some changes might not be pushed back into the 1.4-branch.  With Pyramid on RTD, "latest" means the latest stable, non-development release (1.4.5), whereas "master" means the development release (1.5x).  You might have better luck on the master branch.

http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/master/narr/install.html
http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/master/narr/firstapp.html

Comment: Thank you. I've installed pyramid 1.5a3, but problem "AttributeError: 'PerformanceDebugPanel' object has no attribute '_end_rusage'" still exists.

Comment: You don't provide sufficient information to identify the underlying issue, so the right course of action is to start over.  That said, since you appear to be using PyCharm, I would recommend that you follow [this tutorial](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/01/14/pyramid-requests-responses-and-views/) and its [accompanying video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO52-x2nJ_w).